# Beginner Econometrics question about probabilities for a normal variable

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

$Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)\implies (Y-\mu)/\sigma$

Prove that this has a Mean of $0$ and a Variance of $1$.

Comment: That would be correct if you had $(Y-\mu)/\sigma$, but not if you have $Y-\mu/\sigma$, since that means $Y-(\mu/\sigma)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, that is what I have. Sorry, I wrote it incorrectly. How can I prove it though?

Comment: @Melody: I took the liberty of inserting parentheses as you specified.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a random variable, then $E(X + k) = E(X) + k,$ $E(cX) = c E(X),$
$Var(X + k) = Var(X),$ and $Var(cX) = c^2 Var(X).$
(These are facts for any random variable, including normal variables.)

If you already know these facts, you can use them to determine the mean and variance 
of $Y - \mu,$ then use them again to find your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z$ = $\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma}$.

Then, exploiting expected value's linearity:

$E$$[$$Z$$]$ = $E$$[$$\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma}$$]$  = $\frac{1}{\sigma}($$E$$[$$Y$$]$ - $\mu$) = $0$.

For the variance, since it can be proved that, if $Z$ is a random variable and $a$ a constant:

$Var$$($$a$$Z$$)$ = $a^{2}$$Var$$($$Z$$)$

we find that:

$Var$$($$Z$$)$ = $Var$$($$\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma}$$)$ = $\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$$Var$$($$Y$ - $\mu$$)$

and since, it can also be proved that, if $Z$ is a random variable and $a$ a constant:

$Var$$($$Z$ - $a$$)$ = $Var$$($$Z$$)$

then:

$\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$$Var$$($$Y$ - $\mu$$)$ = $\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}$ = $1$.

Alternatively, for the variance, if you don't want to use the properties, you can go through direct computations as follows:

$Var$$($$\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma}$$)$ = $E$$[$$($$\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma}$ - $E$$[$$\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma}$$]$$)^{2}$$]$ = $E$$[$$($$\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma}$$)^{2}$$]$ = $\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$$($$E$$[$$Y^{2}$$]$ - 2$\mu$$E$$[$$Y$$]$ + $\mu^{2}$$)$

and since $E$$[$$Y$$]$ = $\mu$, plus:

$Var$$[$$Y$$]$ = $E$$[$$($$Y$ - $E$$[$$Y$$]$$)^{2}$$]$ = $E$$[$$Y^{2}$$]$ - $($$E$$[$$Y$$]$$)^{2}$

we can finally conclude that:

$\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$$($$E$$[$$Y^{2}$$]$ - 2$\mu$$E$$[$$Y$$]$ + $\mu^{2}$$)$  = $\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$$($$E$$[$$Y^{2}$$]$ - 2$($$E$$[$$Y$$]$$)^{2}$ + $($$E$$[$$Y$$]$$)^{2}$$)$ = $\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$$($$E$$[$$Y^{2}$$]$ - $($$E$$[$$Y$$]$$)^{2}$$)$ = $\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}$ = $1$.

As last remark, note that I have never used the Normality of $Y$: indeed, the above steps are valid for each random variable, and this process is known in Statistics as Standardization.